# Ruby if else syntax

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app where users can sign up with Facebook, in which case I take the Facebook image, or they can sign up using regular authentication, in which case they're uploading a photo using CarrierWave gem.

Because of some sort of conflict, I had to create a column in the database (`:image`)to store the url to the Facebook image, and then a different column (`:dimage`) to store the url for the image if they signed up using the non-facebook sign up.

So when it comes time to display the user, I'm checking to see if there's an :`image`, and, if not, then displaying the other `:dimage`.

However, I don't want to require them to upload an image, in which case, I want to display an anon image (here represented by the `rails.png`). However, the Rails.png isn't showing up (just a broken image path), so I'm assuming there's some sort of error with my `if else` syntax because the `image_tag("rails.png")` is taken straight from the api

```
 <% if user.image %>
 <%= image_tag user.image %>
 <% elsif user.dimage %>
 <%= image_tag user.dimage_url(:thumb).to_s %>
 <% else %>
 <%= image_tag("rails.png") %>
 <% end %>
```

The generated html on the rails.png

```
<img alt="Assets" src="/assets/">
```

Comment: Your logic is in the wrong place, you should have a simple `image_thumb_url` method on User that returns the appropriate `src` attribute.

Comment: @muistooshort don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Add a method called `image_thumb_url` to your User model, that method would have the `if...else` stuff and your ERB would just be `<%= image_tag user.image_thumb_url %>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `present?` method to check if the attribute is not empty:

```
<% if user.image.present? %>
  <%= image_tag user.image %>
<% elsif user.dimage.present? %>
  <%= image_tag user.dimage_url(:thumb).to_s %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag("rails.png") %>
<% end %>
```

You'll save yourself a headache or two because in Ruby the only falsehoods are `false` and `nil`. This means that the empty string `""` will actually return true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at look into user.image.nil? user.image.empty? and user.image.blank? depending on what you're using and apply the same to the rest of your conditional.  You need to find out specifically what your looking for or the if else won't give you what you want.  I would try empty first which checks if something is nil or is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new rails application, rails stores its logo in PROJECT_PATH/app/assets/images folder. Could you check if that image exists?

Comment: I also tried it with this  <%= image_tag("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10328969/smiley.jpg")%> instead of the rails.png in assets/images but didn't work